# Windows 7. Ошибка при разрешении общего доступа к подключению к Интернету

Tags: windows, сеть, доступ

Здравствуйте.
Имеется два подключения. С главного пытаюсь раздать интернет через вкладку доступ. 
При попытке выдает: "Ошибка при разрешении общего доступа к подключению к Интернету". 
Служба Брандмауэра включена. Avast как в рабочем так и в нерабочем состоянии влияние не оказывается
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А на интерфейсе в сторону Инета какой адресок-то стоИт?

Comment: по мак-адресу выдается адрес

Comment: Я рад за него... а всё-таки - какой? а также какие маска и шлюз...

Comment: так все автоматически выдаваемые, я их в любом случае не сменю. В чем именно суть?

Comment: Ну спрошу более конкретно - не из сети ли 192.168.0.0/24?